# how can i match with current user Id with firebase database data's value?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using vue.js with firebase for shopping website.
I can get the current user id like this below.

```
 data () {
    return {
      cartitems: [],
      user: null,
    }
  },
  created(){

    //get current user
    db.collection('users').where('user_id','==',firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()
    .then(snapshot=>{
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            this.user =doc.data(),
            this.user.id = doc.id
        })
        console.log('get current user id')
        console.log(this.user.id)
        console.log(this.user.alias)    
    })
```

It is working and I can got the current user id and alias.

In 'cartitems', I store the user.alias in 'user'. 
I want to show cartitem in cartitems only "current user alias = cartiems.user". 
but below code isn't working. 
It get the current user alias successfully and i check in console.

```
    db.collection('cartitems').where('user', '==', this.user.alias).get()
       .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            this.cartitem = doc.data()
            this.cartitem.id = doc.id
            this.cartitems.push(cartitem) 

        })
       }).catch(function(error) {
         console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
     })
```

when I fetch all cartitem in cartitems regardless of current user info, 
it's working . Code is below.

```
    db.collection('cartitems').get()
    .then(snapshot =>{
      snapshot.forEach(doc =>{
        let cartitem = doc.data()
        cartitem.id =  doc.id
        this.cartitems.push(cartitem) 
      })
    })
```

I want to show cartitem only matching with current user. please help:)
Thanks.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the database console for a document that you're trying to query. In addition, when you log `this.user.alias` just before the query, what value does it log?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first `db.collection('cartitems').where('user', '==', this.user.alias).get()`. Is it right or wrong? Then i think it's not worked directly like `where('user', '==', this.user.alias)` You should get first key and the you can compare it is way in firebase i hope You understand.